# Match a pattern multiple times

Tags: regex

I'm still new to regular expressions and can't wrap my head arround this.

So I have this pattern:

```
(^%(?!\s)[^%\n]*$)
```

That matches this example:

```
%text here
```

But it does that only one time, it won't match the example multiple times like this:

```
%text here
%text here
```

Is there some "match-multiple-times" option or is the pattern simply not suited for this example?

Comment: You can try `(^%(?!\s)[^%\n]*$)+`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the global option, when matching multiple times, plus "m" flag for multiline

```
(^%(?!\s)[^%\n]*$)/gm
```

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97259

Comment: If the example as provided is correct, it is matching, see the link?